# retrieve property value from state react redux

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-form

I got the state updated but couldn't retrieve value of particular key
. I want to print result like user_added

```js
import React from 'react';
import {Field , reduxForm} from 'redux-form';
import {addUser} from '../actions/index';
import FlatButton from 'material-ui/FlatButton';
import {connect} from 'react-redux';
import TextField from 'material-ui/TextField';
import {RadioButtonGroup , RadioButton} from 'material-ui/RadioButton';
import Result from './User_add_result'

export class Register extends React.Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            role: "",
            username: "",
            email: "",
            token: "",
            password: "",
            userData : ""
        }
        this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
    }

    render() {
       return (
           <div>
           {console.log('result',this.props.userData)}
           {/* {this.props.userData[0]} */}
           {/* {this.props.userData.map(([key , value]) => <p>{value.toString()}</p>)} */}
           {/* <Result result={this.props.userData} /> */}
           </div>
      );
    }
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
    console.log("user result ==========>>>>", state.user[0]);    
    return {
        userData: state.user
    }
}
```

I am getting result like this:

```
result [{…}]0: result: "user_added"__proto__: Objectlength: 1__proto__: Array(0)
```

Comment: what is the output `this.props.userData ` in render?

Comment: result [{…}]0: result: "user_added"proto: Objectlength: 1__proto__: Array(0) this is th eoutput of this.props.userData @RIYAJKHAN

Comment: What does `{this.props.userData.map(item => <p>{item.result.user_added}</p>)}` ?

Comment: Please check `this.props.userData[0].result `

Comment: It didn't work @RIYAJKHAN

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the answer 
Just needed to map single output

```
{ this.props.userData && this.props.userData.map( (user) => user.result)}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the recommended way is to use the `formValueSelector` method shipped with Redux Form.

- [Documentation](https://redux-form.com/7.3.0/docs/api/formvalueselector.md/)
- [Example](https://redux-form.com/7.3.0/examples/selectingformvalues/)